# Weird margin on footer

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I have got a footer on my homepage that weirdly has a margin around it for no apparent reason (seems to me at least). I just want a footer pretty much like the on this very page. Just a plain footer with 100% width. The problem is (as you can hopefully see in the picture I provided), there is a margin on the left, right and bottom of about 9px.

Here is the CSS:

```
#footer_container{

    background: #181818;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
</body>
<div id="footer_container">
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Why is your footer outside of your body???

Comment: Are you sure you removed the margins off the body? `body { margin: 0; }` can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: You also need to define the `position` of the footer to either `absolute` or `relative`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a CSS rule for the HTML body:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

And your `body` should look like this (`div` inside `body`):

```
<body>
    <div id="footer_container">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems the body has a padding/margin by default. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong here, your footer is outside your body:

```
<body>
  <div id="footer_container">
  </div>
</body>
```

And you need to get rid of the margin on the body, then width:100% will work

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
#footer_container{

    background: #181818;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

I've popped it in to a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M62eX/) so you can see it working.

On a side note: if your footer is for some reason deliberately outside the body I *strongly* recommend you change this to ensure compatibility and SEO factors I'm sure are affected by that